# Tengo un problema a la hora de subir archivos a GitHub. Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021

Tags: git, github, login, git-push, git-commit

estoy intentando subir archivos a un repositorio privado de GitHub. He creado el repositorio y también he ejecutado los siguientes comandos:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<my_token_pat>@<mi_usuario>/<repositorio>.git<br/>
git branch -M main/<br/>
git push -u origin main
```

Cuando ejecuto el último comando sale el siguiente error:

[image: Este es el error que me ha salido]

En primer lugar, me gustaría señalar que no estoy intentando subir los archivos a blog-avanzado-drf-react.git, los estoy intentando subir a un repositorio privado; y en segundo lugar soy incapaz de entender porque inenta subir archivos a un repositorio incorrecto.

Comment: Podrías colocar el error como texto en la pregunta?

Comment: Podrías verificar que el URL para origin es el que esperas? Con `git remote get-url origin`

Comment: @Elbailaríndelcódigo acabas de publicar un token de acceso a tu cuenta de GitHub. Esto es un riesgo de seguridad importante. Borra el comentario y revoca el token lo antes posible en tus Settings de GitHub.

Comment: Hace unos días se me apareció el mismo mensaje (Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021) queriendo hacer un push, incluso habiendo agregado el SSH Key en Github. Lo resolví creando el PAT y, cuando en la terminal se me pidió la contraseña, _pegué_ el token (esto en Linux). Demás está decir que hay que guardar el PAT en un lugar seguro. Lo del repositorio incorrecto ya es otro problema :) Aunque ya te dejaron indicaciones de cómo podrías solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Al querer sincronizar de un repositorio privado de GitHub hay dos opciones: por HTTPS o por SSH (recomendable).

### HTTPS

Para añadir un `remote` con las credenciales, la URL es la siguiente:

```bash
git remote add origin https://<USUARIO>:<PAT>@github.com/<CUENTA_DEL_REPO>/<NOMBRE_DEL_REPO>.git
```

De todos modos, si solo se pone la URL del repositorio que te facilita GitHub en el botón verde "Code" (clone -> HTTPS) o la de la barra de direcciones con `.git` al final del nombre del repositorio, debería aceptarla igualmente y pedir credenciales (desde el propio gestor de credenciales de Git, o el del sistema).

### SSH (recomendado)

Usando SSH, tienes una clave privada en tu equipo y una clave pública que subes a GitHub para que este pueda autenticarte. De forma que, cada vez que hagas un `push` o cualquier otra operación, GitHub sabrá quien eres y los permisos que tienes, sin tener que generar PAT para cada equipo ni reintroducir credenciales una y otra vez.

Para hacer esto, hay que generar la clave y subirla (debería funcionar en Windows, MacOS y Linux):

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "PRUEBA STACKOVERFLOW"
```

El comando preguntará el archivo donde se quiere guardar la clave, pulsa enter para dejarlo por defecto (dará menos problemas a posteriori). Después pedirá una *passphrase* (frase de contraseña), que es recomendable pero no necesaria, y se te pedirá cada vez que uses la clave. Puedes pulsar enter dos veces sin escribir nada, para dejarla vacía.

Una vez generada, vas a la ruta donde te dice que se ha generado, y copias el contenido del archivo `id_rsa.pub`, o como se llame la clave. Lo indica el comando al terminar: `Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\<USUARIO>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

En GitHub parte superior derecha donde la foto de perfil haces click -> Settings -> SSH and GPG Keys (Access) -> New SSH key y pones un "title" que desees y pegas la clave en "Key". Pulsando el botón verde de create, ya debería estar listo.

[image: Una captura de GitHub demostrando cómo queda el formulario de adición de clave SSH]

Ahora, para cada repositorio, el comando de clonado será el siguiente:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:<USUARIO_DEL_REPO>/<REPOSITORIO>.git
```

Nótese que `git@github.com` siempre se utiliza, ya que por SSH se usa siempre el usuario `git`, y el sistema te identifica por la clave pública. Luego, entre `github.com` y el nombre del repositorio va `:` como separador, y no una `/` como ocurre en HTTPS. De todos modos, la URL para copiar está disponible en el botón verde Code -> Clone -> SSH.

Para configurar otro equipo, basta con repetir los pasos aquí mencionados. Si ya tienes una clave para conectarte a un servidor por SSH, no hace falta crear una clave nueva, basta con usar la que ya tengas generada. Esta configuración vale para GitHub y otros servicios similares como GitLab, BitBucket, servidores de Gitea...

Comment: He seguido los pasos correctamente y sigue saliendo el mismo error:

Clonando en 'desktop-tutorial'...
gh auth git-credential: "erase" operation not supported
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Autenticación falló para 'https://github.com/astroinfinito/blog-avanzado-drf-react.git/' ¿Por qué sigue intentando subir los archivos a otro repositorio?

Comment: @Elbailaríndelcódigo probablemente tengas mal la URL del repositorio. Mira que `git remote get-url origin` devuelva la URL correcta. Y si no, ejecuta `git remote set-url origin <LA URL CORRECTA PARA SSH>` y después prueba a hacer `git fetch`